# ng command does not execute <as> tag in Dockerfile

Tags: angular, docker

While I am developing Docker+Django+Angular, I have faced an annoying problem.

I made a Dockerfile in angular project.
It contains the command below:

```
FROM node:11.4.0-alpine as builder
.....
.....
```

But if i run the command: docker-compose up
  it says:

```
   ERROR: Service 'ng' failed to build: Error parsing reference:
          "node:11.4.0-alpine AS builder" is not a valid repository/tag:
          invalid reference format
```

my ng version info:
     Angular CLI: 8.3.4
     Node: 12.5.0
     OS: darwin x64

Of course, if I don't use 'as' tag, there is no error.
But I have a reason to use 'as' tag.
If you have an answer, please drop your words.

Comment: Share your complete docker , the error not due to base image tag only

Comment: thanks. the reason is because of docker version. in my docker version(17.3.0) can not recognize 'as'. so I updated it.